# Command History of proc_open for php

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to access the command history of php's proc_open function? I am attempting to see if there is any storage of the commands for security purposes.

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of. PHP doesn't automatically keep any logs of normal actions, just errors and warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `proc_open()` does not keep any kind of history whatsoever, nor does `exec()`. However, you could wrap it when you use it in your code such that it does; but, you'd have to write your own history handling. Even `shell_exec()` doesn't seem to track history.

But, if we ignore PHP for a bit, we can use Linux's Audit Subsystem to track all commands executed on the system. A daemon called `auditd` does this logging, and you can configure it via `auditctl`. [Here](http://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/) is some more information about the Audit Subsystem, setting it up, and using it.

To log all commands executed, and their arguments, use:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S execve
```

The logs should show up in `/var/log/audit.log`, or wherever your distribution places audit logs.

There are many options for `auditctl` to specify which programs are logged and which users' activity is logged.

You can use the `-F euid=<UID OF PHP USER>` or `-F uid=<UID OF PHP USER>` to limit this to the PHP/Apache user.

Comment: I appreciate the information on how to save the command history but my security concerns are about not wanting to save it. Is there documentation anywhere that states that it doesn't track history?

Comment: @Bwata No, because there's no reason to expect it would. Shell history files only track commands that were typed into interactive shells, not every command that was run directly or indirectly on the system.